# What is the difference between toBeInTheDocument() and toBeVisible()?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In react testing library, we have two functions called `toBeInTheDocument()` and `toBeVisible()`.

```
1 expect(screen.getByText('hello')).toBeInTheDocument();
2 expect(screen.getByText('hello')).toBeVisible();
```

It seems both assertions behave the same. What is their difference, and what are the use cases for each?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these assertions but here are a couple of general points: 1. You can have a node the DOM but currently not visible. 2. Visibility might not just be "visible = true" but also *shown on the screen*. If an element is off the viewport, it might be considered not visible.

Answer (score 41):

According to the [testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible) documentation,

**[toBeInTheDocument](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobeinthedocument)** simply finds element is in DOM Tree regardless of visibility

**[toBeVisible](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible)** checks for multiple attributes to see if it's visible such as

1. `display` not equal to `none`
2. `opacity` greater than `0`
3. `hidden` attribute does not exist
4. `visibility` not equal to `hidden` or `collapse`
5. checks for element, if it's document and parent is visible

Comment: Do either take into account elements height? If the height of the element has been set to `0` with overflow hidden (often used in animations) is there a way to check if that element is no longer visible?

Comment: @Stretch0 No, neither take it into account. There are also no plans to support it either: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/450 . In the issues thread you can see some of the workarounds listed however.

Comment: toBeVisible() seems like the better choice, is there a reason the official docs default to toBeInTheDocument() instead?