# How to test if the button closes the popup succesfully?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have a simple pop-up that I want to test if the clicked button closes the popup using testing-library/react. The way shown in docs doesn't work for me for some reason. I'm able to console log the button, so the query works but fireEvent doesn't trigger the button.

```
 test("close the popup", () => {

  render(
    <Popup>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </Popup>
  );

  const button = screen.getByText("Got It");


  fireEvent.click(button);


  expect(button).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});



import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Popup = (props) => {
  const id = "popup-active"
  const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(() => {
    const value = window.localStorage.getItem(id);
    return value !== null ? JSON.parse(value) : true;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(id, popupActive);
  }, [popupActive]);

  const handleX = () => {
    setPopupActive(!popupActive);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        visibility: popupActive ? "visible" : "hidden",
        opacity: popupActive ? "1" : "0",
      }}
      className={popupStyles.overlay}
    >
      <div className={popupStyles.popup}>
        <div className={popupStyles.content}>{props.children}</div>
        <button
          data-testid="button-popup"
          className={popupStyles.button}
          onClick={handleX}
        >
          Got It
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popup;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [toBeVisible](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible) matcher.

> This allows you to check if an element is currently visible to the user.
> An element is visible if all the following conditions are met:
>
> - it is present in the document
> - it does not have its css property display set to none
> - it does not have its css property visibility set to either hidden or collapse
> - it does not have its css property opacity set to 0
> - its parent element is also visible (and so on up to the top of the DOM tree)
> - it does not have the hidden attribute
> - if `<details />` it has the open attribute

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const id = 'popup-active';
const Popup = (props) => {
  const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(() => {
    const value = window.localStorage.getItem(id);
    return value !== null ? JSON.parse(value) : true;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(id, popupActive);
  }, [popupActive]);

  const handleX = () => {
    setPopupActive(!popupActive);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        visibility: popupActive ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
        opacity: popupActive ? '1' : '0',
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
        <button data-testid="button-popup" onClick={handleX}>
          Got It
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popup;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import Popup from './';

describe('73407176', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    render(
      <Popup>
        <div id="content"></div>
      </Popup>
    );

    const button = screen.getByText('Got It');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(button).not.toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73407176/index.test.tsx (11.549 s)
  73407176
    ✓ should pass (73 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |    83.33 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |    83.33 |     100 |     100 | 8                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.167 s
```

Also check this question: [What is the difference between toBeInTheDocument() and toBeVisible()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852702/what-is-the-difference-between-tobeinthedocument-and-tobevisible)